# super simple cipher function in python. comparing a list to keys in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am working on ways to get me thinking in python. I have a simple idea that will take a number and give the corresponding "value" from a dictionary.

So basically I would like to have a number or numbers given, and then turn those numbers into a word.

The overall all view is to have a dictionary with keys ranging for 1 to 26 with values going from a to z. So 1 would equal "a" and 26 would equal "z".

I have a variable d = 1, and need to get the output of 'a'. Then increase size of this function for a list like (1,2,3,4) which output would be a, b, c, d.

Here is what I have so far.

```
d = 1

def code_scram(x):


    c = {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'd', 5: 'e', 6: 'f', 7: 'g', 8: 'h', 9: 'i', 10: 'j', 11: 'k', 12: 'l', 13: 'm', 14: 'n', 15: 'o', 16: 'p', 17: 'q', 18: 'r', 19: 's', 20: 't', 21: 'u', 22: 'v', 23: 'w', 24: 'x', 25: 'y', 26: 'z'}

    scram = ""

    for i in d:
        if i in c:
            scram += c[i]
    return scram

print code_scram(d)
```

However, its not working out as planned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `for` loop should iterate through `x`, not `d`.

```
def code_scram(x):
    c = {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'd', 5: 'e', 6: 'f', 7: 'g', 8: 'h', 9: 'i', 10: 'j', 11: 'k', 12: 'l', 13: 'm', 14: 'n', 15: 'o', 16: 'p', 17: 'q', 18: 'r', 19: 's', 20: 't', 21: 'u', 22: 'v', 23: 'w', 24: 'x', 25: 'y', 26: 'z'}
    scram = ""
    for i in x:
        if i in c:
            scram += c[i]
    return scram

print code_scram([1,2,3,4])
```

Result:

```
abcd
```

The function only works for lists, so passing in the integer `d` won't work. Pass in a list instead.

```
d = [1]
print code_scram(d)
```

If you want the function to work for lists *and* lone integers, you can perform a type check, and convert as necessary.

```
def code_scram(x):
    if isinstance(x, int):
        x = [x]
    c = {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'd', 5: 'e', 6: 'f', 7: 'g', 8: 'h', 9: 'i', 10: 'j', 11: 'k', 12: 'l', 13: 'm', 14: 'n', 15: 'o', 16: 'p', 17: 'q', 18: 'r', 19: 's', 20: 't', 21: 'u', 22: 'v', 23: 'w', 24: 'x', 25: 'y', 26: 'z'}
    scram = ""
    for i in x:
        if i in c:
            scram += c[i]
    return scram

d = 1
print code_scram(d)
```

Result:

```
a
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin! I understand better now.

Comment: Just a suggestion--- `if isinstance(x, collections.Iterable)` instead